# How to 'use' a required dependency installed via composer PHP

Tags: php, composer-php, dependency-management

I have installed the SoundCloud API wrapper into my project via composer using `composer require ise/php-soundcloud 3.*`. Now in my project, how do I use that? In my composer.json file I have

```
"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "ise/php-soundcloud": "3.*",
        "njasm/soundcloud": "dev-master"
    },
```

The wrapper I am trying to 'use' is `"ise/php-soundcloud": "3.*"`. The other SoundCloud related file is the wrapper I'm currently using, however I would like to switch over. I am able to 'use' that one by saying `use Njasm\Soundcloud\SoundcloudFacade;` at the top of whatever class I am trying to call it from. But for some reason I am not able to get the other one working, or recognized by my IDE (PhpStorm).

Comment: I teseted this with a fresh L5 install and got phpstorm to recognise it using `use Soundcloud\Service;`. Seemed to work fine

Comment: hi. Im' the author of njasm-soundcloud, thanks for trying out my library. if you're using laravel5 you can look for the laravel serviceprovider. at packagist.org -> laravel5-soundcloud . btw did you find any issues using my library? if so I invite you to report the issue in github.com/njasm/soundcloud. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I teseted this with a fresh L5 install and got phpstorm to recognise it using `use Soundcloud\Service;`. Seemed to work fine.  To figure it out I looked in the `vendor/ise` directory and has a look at the `Service.php`.

This showed it used the Soundcloud namespace. If I were to use this properly though I would probably use `use Soundcloud\Service as SoundcloudService` just so it woudl make sense.

This would allow me to use `$myScService = new SoundcloudService($clientId, $clientSecret);`